# Vertical bars in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame in R like this:

```
X    L     U
1    2     3
2    1.5   5
.....  
3    1.2   3.4
```

For each value of X, I want to plot a vertical bar going from Y=L to Y=U. How can I do this in ggplot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `geom_segment` for that.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x=X)) +
  geom_segment(aes(xend=X, y=L, yend=U))
```

[image]

---

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(X=1:3, L=c(2,1.5,1.2), U=c(3,5,3.4))
```

Answer (score 0):

Also with `geom_tile()`:

```
dat <- data.frame(
  x = 1:10,
  l = rnorm(10, 2, 1),
  u = rnorm(10, 1)
)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(dat, aes(x = x, y = l, height = l + u)) +
  geom_tile(fill = 'skyblue', color = 'antiquewhite') +
  ggthemes::theme_wsj() +
  labs(title = 'so#75578969')
```

[image]